# My Zend Framework Routes are not stacking properly

Tags: zend-framework

I have one module (site) in my zend framework app. What I am trying to do is first to check if controller/action exists and if not then try to match the URL against some custom routes.

My code in _bootstrap.php is as follows:

```
$router = $this->frontController->getRouter();
$router->removeDefaultRoutes();

// catalog category product route
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':categoryIdent/:productIdent',
        array(
            'action'        => 'view',
            'controller'    => 'product',
            'module'        => 'site',
            'categoryIdent' => '',
            'productIdent' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'categoryIdent' => '[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+',
            'productIdent'  => '[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+'
        )
);

$router->addRoute('catalog_category_product', $route);


$router->addDefaultRoutes();
```

I know that the routes in Zend Framework are matched backwards. So I tried the following URLs.

1. example.com/site/index/index -> OK  (executing action/controller => index/index)
2. example.com/bags/bag-7       -> OK  (executing action/controller => product/view)
3. example.com/index/index      -> WRONG ( executing action/controller => product/view, but this should be a part from the default routes, which are defined at the end)

This is the problem and I don't understand why the default  controller/action route is not applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third example matches the pattern of your catalog_category_product-route. That is why it is send to product/view.

You could try to add requirements to :productIdent and/or :categoryIdent, so that index/index does not match these requirements.

[The reference manual explains how to set variable requirements](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard.variable-requirements).

edit: I missed, that you already placed requirements. But index/index still does match :categoryIndent/:productIndent. You could use the following regex for :productIndent, assuming that it is always word - dash - number:

```
'/^([a-z]+-[0-9]+)$/'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mahok.  I am aware that the third example matches the "catalog_category_product" route. But it should not be used, because there are default routes that also are a match. In the third case  index/index is a valid controller/action pair.  This is the problem I am looking answer for.

Comment: In that case you should keep in mind, in what order routes are matched. Your route is added after the default route, therefore it will be matched before it (LIFO - last in, first out). Anyways, changing the routes' order won't help you, as this would break 2., because it will match the default route. The best way to solve your problem (in my opinion) would be, to prefix your route with a static text like `catalog/:categoryIdent/:productIdent` [edit: or by having a more restrictive requirement in your route, like shown in my answer]

Comment: You say that my custom route is added after the default route, but it is not. As you can see in the example code I first remove the default route, add my custom route and then I add my default route again. Changing the routes is not an option because then I will not be able to match controllers/actions using default routes.   I know that I could use a prefix, but I am curious why route number 3 is not matched in the example. This is my question. Anyway thank you for the effort. I appreciate it!

Comment: Your default route matches `:module/:controller/:action`, whereas your route matches `:categoryIdent/:productIdent`. The url `index/index` does clear not match the default route, but your route. That is why it uses `ProductController::viewAction()`. But even if you specify a route between default and your route without `:module`, you would have the problem that either `bags/bag-7` OR `index/index` would match an unwanted route. That is why you either have to refine the requirements for your route or add a more specific route afterwards matching only index/index specifically.

Comment: I just saw my mistake. The ZF manual says, that "Invalid module maps to controller name". But it doesn't say that invalid module/controller maps to controller/action like I presumed. Thanks for the help mahok. :)